# TypeError in Python for list of tuples finding the max based on 2nd element

Tags: python, list, tuples, typeerror

I have a larger list of tuples of the form

```
num_list = [('A15', 2, 'BC', 721.16), ('A21', 3, 'AB', 631.31), ('A42', 4, 'EE', 245.43)]
```

And I'm trying to find the largest fourth element across a rolling 5 number interval of the 2nd element using the code below:

```
min = 1
max = 5

result = max([i for i in num_list if i[1] <= max and i[1] >= min], key = lambda  x:x[3])
```

This is just for a static 5 number interval, I was going to use a for loop when I could get this to work. The code works fine when I comment out min and max and set max and min to 5 and 1 respectively in the result. However, when I put in the min and max variables I get a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Don't name your variables the same thing as built-in functions.

Comment: @kvmahesh: Stop trying to put things in code formatting that don't belong in code formatting.